Resolving electrostatic forces using electrostatic pressure
I stumbled upon a problem involving:
2 charged hemispheres with surface charged density σ are left to touch but not stick to each other, the hemispheres form a complete sphere(but not stuck together) over another conducting spherical shell of a radius half of the hemispheres.
It was asked to calculate the surface charge density required on the smaller conducting shell to keep the system in equilibrium.
What I tried:
I know that the electrostatic pressure is given by σ^2/2ε0, ofcourse, one hemisphere exerts a force of this pressure*πR^2.
Now the conducting shell may have a surface charge density of say, ∆.
I tried to use electrostatic pressure again due to this shell but it proved feeble, I could not calculate it due to it being inside, I remain stumped and await more approaches!

The formula for electrostatic pressure that you have here is only correct for conductors, it happens to be correct for a uniformly charged sphere because a conducting sphere would also get uniformly charged if you were to charge it. First calculate the repulsive force between outer half shells (They do in fact exert electrostatic "pressure" on each other, of the value that you gave), then you need to realize that interaction force between one hemisphere and inside smaller sphere (if they are uniformly charged) is the same if you would replace inside sphere with a point charge at the centre.
